# puppeteer used in docker image

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker

I'm having a nodejs project with a service that generate pdf using puppeteer. the project work perfect in local (windows) but when i create the docker image (in debian) i got this error :

Error in processing: Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome ENOENT

TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

```
at onClose (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:750:14)
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:741:65)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:12)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

i've tried all the solution proposed in this forum but none works, any idea please

- i tried to install dependencies in dockerfile
- install locate-chrome and use locateshrome